# Stopping update of an attribute of a table to a particular status if that status already exists with another attribute of that table

Tags: mysql, count

I've two tables. months_with_years and months_with_years_status. I don't want more than one month_with_year_id with status 'Ongoing'. If i try to update the status of a month_with_year_id  to 'Ongoing' while another one month_with_year_id having 'Ongoing', I want my counter to show 1 and to stop update.

```
CREATE TABLE `months_with_years` (
month_with_year_id INT(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
month_with_year_mwy VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (month_with_year_id),
UNIQUE (month_with_year_mwy)
);
CREATE TABLE `months_with_years_status` (
month_with_year_id INT(2),
status_of_month_with_year VARCHAR(50),
FOREIGN KEY (month_with_year_id)
    REFERENCES months_with_years (month_with_year_id)
);

delimiter $$
create trigger trigger_2
after insert on months_with_years
for each row 
begin 
insert into months_with_years_status(month_with_year_id, 
status_of_month_with_year)
values (new.month_with_year_id,'Status has not been updated yet');

end$$
delimiter ;

insert into months_with_years 
values(1,'1-2019'),(2,'2-2019'),(3,'3-2019');

update months_with_years_status 
set  status_of_month_with_year='Ongoing'
where month_with_year_id=1;

update months_with_years_status 
set  status_of_month_with_year='Ongoing'
where month_with_year_id=2;
```

I'm trying to get count_of_ongoing_status_YearMonth value 1 when count will happen.

```
select count(*) as count_of_ongoing_status_YearMonth
from months_with_years_status 
where status_of_month_with_year='Ongoing' having count(*) like '%Ongoing%' = 1;
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for  check the count you just need

```
select count(*) as count_of_ongoing_status_YearMonth
from months_with_years_status 
where status_of_month_with_year='Ongoing' having count(*) = 1;
```

could be you need these for each month_with_year_id .. fore this you could use  group by

```
select month_with_year_id , count(*) as count_of_ongoing_status_YearMonth
from months_with_years_status 
where status_of_month_with_year='Ongoing' 
group by month_with_year_id 
having count(*) = 1;
```

Comment: a little bit modification and the second query worked fine for me sir.

Comment: well .. i was answering but i think you have already done just adding where month_with_year_id  = ?   ..